# Excel formula in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, excel-formula

I have a DataFrame...

```
data = {"Col1":[57600, 42375, 417225, 30600, 60375], "Col2": [9300, 9400, 9500, 9600, 9700],"Col3": [802350, 950700, 2800875, 1170300, 1616175]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I want to calculate two new columns as col1_loss & col3_loss to get following output DataFrame....

```
 Col1   Col2    Col3    Col1_loss   Col3_loss
57600   9300    802350  0   19356195000
42375   9400    950700  5760000 16442610000
417225  9500    2800875 15757500    13624095000
30600   9600    1170300 67477500    11085667500
60375   9700    1616175 122257500   8664270000
105375  9800    2592900 183075000   6404490000
143100  9900    2419650 254430000   4404000000
849150  10000   5884350 340095000   2645475000
2140050 10100   4750200 510675000   1475385000
4535850 10200   3083400 895260000   780315000
3926250 10300   1293525 1733430000  393585000
4585425 10400   1211700 2964225000  136207500
6285375 10500   1362075 4653562500  0
3823875 10600   603750  6971437500  -136207500
2846325 10700   252375  9671700000  -332790000
2856675 10800   248700  12656595000 -554610000
```

In Excel I'm using ....

For col1_loss

```
=IFERROR($B2*SUM(A2:$A$2)-SUMPRODUCT($B2:B$2,$A2:A$2),0)
```

For col3_loss

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($B2:B$14,$C2:C$14)-$B2*SUM($C2:C$14),0)
```

In my Excel A=col1, B=col2 & C=col3 and first row is header ofcourse.

How to do that in pandas ????
My DataFrame may have variable no. of rows from 30 to 70.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sumproduct(Excel) like calculations in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76904628/sumproductexcel-like-calculations-in-dataframe)

Comment: @Jonas Horsch I deleted that one..

Comment: `Col3_loss` is not clear. Can you check your formula? It doesn't give the output you provided.

Comment: @Jonas Horsch I updated my output. Plz check again

Comment: col3_loss Excel formula also updated

Comment: Please edit your question to include enough data such that col3_loss can be checked more easily.

Comment: Are the ranges in col3_loss intended to be from current row to row 14? What about when current row is greater than row 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Ok, I did not get your use of ranges right, the first time: Use `cumsum`:

```py
df["Col1_loss"] = df["Col2"] * df["Col1"].cumsum() - (df["Col1"] * df["Col2"]).cumsum()
```

For the up-side down col-loss, you can use `df.loc[::-1]` to turn your table upside-down and then do the same:

```py
df["Col3_loss"] = (df["Col2"] * df["Col3"]).loc[::-1].cumsum() - df["Col2"] * df.loc[::-1, "Col3"].cumsum()
```

this produces different values to what you are showing, but i think there are rows missing, so different results are expected.

Comment: No, not helpful

Comment: Horsch Plz review col3_loss script... In Excel formula there is little bit difference. Here in col3_loss SUMPRODUCT coming first which is opposite to in col1_loss formula

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia The SUMPRODUCT corresponds to `(df["Col2"] * df["Col3"]).loc[::-1].cumsum()` which is also first in my answer, so this difference is accounted for.

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia For the updated data it looks like your excel formula is wrong, which is only going up to line 14 instead of going down to the last line 17.

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia Ok, glad, it did. For the future: If you want to get repeated help on stackoverflow, you need to be more humble, acknowledge the work other people are putting into their answers (a thanks also for partial answers would be appropriate, for instance) and make it as easy as possible to help you (ie add a description of what you want to do, instead of having them chase after bits of information). People here like helping, but they don't like doing your work. Take care

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I'm not much familiar with responding/accepting/describing options available on this website so I have this poor response.

Answer (score 0):

Use `expanding`:

```
df["Col1_loss"] = df["Col2"].mul(df["Col1"].expanding().sum())-df["Col1"].mul(df["Col2"]).expanding().sum()

df["Col3_loss"] = df["Col3"].mul(df["Col2"]).expanding().sum()-df["Col2"].mul(df["Col3"].expanding().sum())
```

Comment: What for col3_loss ??? Let me check formula.

Comment: Your formula doesn't give the output you have in the OP. Fix your formula or update your expected output.

Comment: Something wrong with col3_loss

Comment: Why do you only calculate up to row 14 for `Col3_loss`? Explain the math in words (not formulas) in your post

Comment: Sir I need to calculate all the rows in DataFrame which is variable in number. You can calculate from row 1 to last row of DataFrame. I'm unable to explain math as I'm not good enough to post on this website. Furthermore plz review once col1_loss and col3_loss formula which is different. So changing columns will not give the result. It is almost reverse to col1_loss formula.Thanks